# useEffect re rendering all the time

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

i have already posted questions here regarding my humble attempt at creating a space invader type of game ! 
this time i am having troubles with useEffect rerendering everytime i shoot a laser, leading to launching a setintervall again everytime i hit shoot, and then my lasers are going faster and faster !! is the solution placing my setInterval elsewhere, or working on the useEffect so it does not render when i shoot a laser ??
here is my updated sandbox :

https://codesandbox.io/s/mfcqd?file=/src/MainGameContainer.jsx

i am guessing the probleme lies in './src/gameElements/lasers.jsx' and it's the useEffect at the beggining of the function that keeps on rendering everytime i shoot.

thank you if anaone can help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear the interval in your useEffect cleanup, otherwise when component re-rerenders, the old interval is still there:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let timing = setInterval(moveLasers, 30);
    return () => clearInterval(timing);
  });
```

Comment: oh yes i tried that but probably did it the wrong way, thsk so much !!